# Django redirect in views if context don´t exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a template that needs one session variable to show the information. I want to configure my template in case the information don´t came to the template then redirect the user to other template. This is how my code looks now and the error that return

```
class Feedback(TemplateView):
template_name = 'cursos/pu.html'
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = self.request.session.get('user_id')
    username = self.request.session.get('username')
    password = self.request.session.get('password')
    apiKey = self.request.session.get('apiKeyUser')
    complete_name = self.request.session.get('complete_name')
    context = super(Feedback, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['firstname'] = self.request.session.get('firstname')
    if self.request.session['quizResult'] != None:
            context['quizResult'] = self.request.session['quizResult']
            self.request.session['quizResult'] = None
            self.request.session.modified = True
            return context
    else:
        return redirect('core:home') #feedback
    return context
```

The error is: `'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

How can I modify that to redirect to home in case `self.request.session['quizResult'] == None`

Comment: You're crossing two different methods here, `get` and `get_context_data`

Comment: Yes @Sayse, You are rigth. I made the `change to get_context_data` and I works, but after refresh the session variable is None again(that is how to suppose to work) but not redirect to the `home` template. How can I redirect in the `get_context_data`. Now the error after refresh is `context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect` because the redirect